# How to get the Mongo database specified in connection string in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to connect to the database specified in the connection string, without specifying it again in `GetDatabase`.

For example, if I have a connection string like this;

```
mongodb://localhost/mydb
```

I would like to be able to `db.GetCollection("mycollection")` from `mydb`.

This would allow the database name to be configured easily in the app.config file.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**Update:**

`MongoServer.Create` is obsolete now (thanks to @aknuds1). Instead this use following code:

```
var _server = new MongoClient(connectionString).GetServer();
```

---

It's easy. You should first take database name from connection string and then get database by name. Complete example:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27020/mydb";

//take database name from connection string
var _databaseName = MongoUrl.Create(connectionString).DatabaseName;
var _server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);

//and then get database by database name:
_server.GetDatabase(_databaseName);
```

**Important**: If your database and auth database are different, you can add a authSource= query parameter to specify a different auth database. (thank you to  [@chrisdrobison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601029/chrisdrobison))

[From docs:](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/)

> NOTE If you are using the database segment as the initial database to
>   use, but the username and password specified are defined in a
>   different database, you can use the authSource option to specify the
>   database in which the credential is defined. For example,
>   mongodb://user:pass@hostname/db1?authSource=userDb would authenticate
>   the credential against the userDb database instead of db1.

Comment: Ah, ok - I see my problem. I don't have access to the connection string, but only the already-created MongoServer object. And it doesn't appear to know about the connection string-specified database. Thanks.

Comment: MongoServer.Create is obsolete.

Comment: Deleted my last comment since it wasn't quite correct. One thing to note though is that according to the Mongo docs, that it also telling the driver which database you want to auth against. If your database and auth database are different, you can add a authSource= query parameter to specify a different auth database.

Comment: @chrisdrobison Thank you! This important to know (updated my answer)! The question was answered 3.5 years ago. Things changed :)

Answer (score 32):

In this moment with the last version of the C# driver (2.3.0) the only way I found to get the database name specified in connection string is this:

```
var connectionString = @"mongodb://usr:pwd@srv1.acme.net,srv2.acme.net,srv3.acme.net/dbName?replicaSet=rset";
var mongoUrl = new MongoUrl(connectionString);
var dbname = mongoUrl.DatabaseName;
var db = new MongoClient(mongoUrl).GetDatabase(dbname);
db.GetCollection<MyType>("myCollectionName");
```

Comment: This should be upvoted, altough I know this is an old thread. This is the only way to get this in Version 2.3. Thanks for the answer, it took some searching to get here.

Answer (score 10):

With version 1.7 of the official 10gen driver, this is the current (non-obsolete) API:

```
const string uri = "mongodb://localhost/mydb";
var client = new MongoClient(uri);
var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase(new MongoUrl(uri).DatabaseName);
var collection = db.GetCollection("mycollection");
```

Comment: fwif: This also works in Xamarin Studio 5.8.1 using the mongo driver 1.10

Answer (score 5):

The answer below is apparently obsolete now, but works with older drivers. See comments.

If you have the connection string you could also use MongoDatabase directly:

```
var db =  MongoDatabase.Create(connectionString);
var coll = db.GetCollection("MyCollection");
```

Comment: As time passed, MongoDatabase.Create() has been obsoleted since driver version 1.7

Comment: @runTarm But time goes on, and the specification of database names in C# mongo connection strings is not getting obsoleted.