# How do I get the current/default database (MongoDB, official C# driver)?

Tags: c#, mongodb

[The C# driver tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial) gives the following format for the connection string (which includes the option to specify a default database):

```
mongodb://[username:password@]hostname[:port][/[database][?options]]
```

But I don't see an overload of the GetDatabase method that doesn't require providing the database name.  Is there some other method of getting a MongoDatabase instance that represents the database specified in the connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an overload for that. You could use this approach instead:

```
var db = MongoDatabase.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017/SomeDatabase");
var collection = db.GetCollection("MyCollection");
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.  I didn't realize I could just create the Database object without first going though the MongoServer object.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, MongoDatabase.Create is now marked as obsolete. I wonder what the replacement for this scenario is?

Comment: This answer shows a way to do it without using the obsolete MongoDatabase.Create method. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7202105/431891
In short, you use MongoUrl.Create to parse a MongoUrl object from the connection string, and use its DatabaseName property.